# Notepad++ FTP crashes on connecting to VMS via FTP

Tags: notepad++, ftp, openvms

**Background:**

I'm using notepad++ version 7.6.4 with NppFTP plugin version 0.27.5 Unicode.
I have a VAX (VMS) server that I connect to.
I could connect to the server using other FTP clients like Reflection FTP and KEA!.
But to edit files and to do comparison directly from notepad++ would be a great advantage to me.

**Problem:**

When I configure the profile settings of the NppFTP and connect, the application crashes. I'm able to login with username and password. Something goes wrong when `STRU F` command is being passed or being executed.
Here is the snapshot of the messages window from NppFTP.
[image]
The image is faint because the application has crashed already.

**Efforts:**

- I have searched the notepad community for similar questions, but could not find one.
- I have changed the FTP type from active to passive and back to passive. Doesn't help.
- Did not provide any initial directory in the host. Still had the problem.
  Provided a path of the initial directory, the problem stil exists.

What else should I be doing? I understand that the FTP command STRU F is just asking for the directory structure from the FTP server (VAX-VMS server). But I don't see a way to stop NppFTP from doing it

Comment: Have you tried [the latest version 0.28.3](https://github.com/ashkulz/NppFTP/releases/tag/v0.28.3)? Also [report the issue](https://github.com/ashkulz/NppFTP/issues) to the developer

Comment: Cannot try the latest version at the office. Some issues with whitelisting. I have asked the developer in Github